# Create generic class or interface with self typed parameters in children classes

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, interface, delphi-xe2

I'd like to create a class or interface that I could subclass, always using current class instances as methods parameters...

Here is an example to explain my problem:

```
 type IArithmeticObject = interface(IInterface)
   procedure assign(ao : IArithmeticObject);
   procedure add(ao : IArithmeticObject);
   procedure remove(ao : IArithmeticObject);
   procedure multiply(ao : IArithmeticObject);
   procedure divide(ao : IArithmeticObject);
 end;
```

the interface `IArithmeticObject` whould be the starting point, referencing basic arithmetic operations and child classes could be declared as

```
 type TInteger = class(TInterfacedObject, IArithmeticObject)
   procedure assign(ao : TInteger);
   procedure add(ao : TInteger);
   procedure remove(ao : TInteger);
   procedure multiply(ao : TInteger);
   procedure divide(ao : TInteger);
 end;
```

with parameter type for `ao` being `TInteger` and not `IArithmeticObject`.

Another idea would be to use a self referencing generic type like:

```
  AMathObject = class;

  AMathObject<T : AMathObject, constructor> = class
    procedure assign(ao : T);virtual;abstract;
    procedure add(ao : T);virtual;abstract;
    procedure remove(ao : T);virtual;abstract;
    procedure multiply(ao : T);overload;virtual;abstract;
    procedure divide(ao : T);virtual;abstract;
  end;
```

but I could not figure out the right syntax...

Does anyone have any ideas about this possibility (or impossibility)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undestand it correctly, you may want to derive your class from a generic interface.

```
type
  IArithmeticObject<T> = interface
    procedure assign(ao: IArithmeticObject<T>);
    procedure add(ao: IArithmeticObject<T>);
    procedure remove(ao: IArithmeticObject<T>);
    procedure multiply(ao: IArithmeticObject<T>);
    procedure divide(ao: IArithmeticObject<T>);
  end;

  TInteger = class (TInterfacedObject, IArithmeticObject<TInteger>)
    procedure assign(ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>);
    procedure add(ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>);
    procedure remove(ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>);
    procedure multiply(ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>);
    procedure divide(ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>);
  end;
```

Answer edited according to the [Stefan Glienke's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273793/create-generic-class-or-interface-with-self-typed-parameters-in-children-classes#comment58283530_35275162): now the methods of the class accept parameters declared either as objects or interfaces.

```
var
  ao: IArithmeticObject<TInteger>;
begin
  ao := TInteger.Create;
  ao.multiply(ao);
end.
```

Comment: While that works it does not make much sense because then you are mixing interfaces and object references in the API. You want to use `IArithmeticObject<TInteger>` but can only pass `TInteger` to its methods. So imo it would make more sense if you change the parameters on the methods of `IArithmeticObject<T>` from `T` to `IArithmeticObject<T>`.